# How is called this type of web vulnerability?

Tags: html, security, web-applications, terminology

In a hacking challenge I've found something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1500" name="price">
```

This challenge makes you understand that if you are smart enough to change the value (which is imposed by the client-side of the web application), you can basically change the price of the item, before buying it.
This is a well-known vulnerability that affects web application but I really don't know how to name this type of vulnerability more precisely..any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not "hacking", you're just editing `HTML` values.

Comment: yes indeed, but it is a web application vulnerability..

Comment: Anyone who trusts a user should not make dynamic websites. Even trusted user's input needs to be validated. Mistakes are so easy to make. But I feel it's illegal to fall for this nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

This is known as [Web Parameter Tampering](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering), or as [External Control of Assumed-Immutable Web Parameter (CWE-472)](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/472.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would categorize it as a Client-side vulnerability.  While it is unheard for developers to use hidden fields to store information that could be considered sensitive, someone new to developing may use it for a "simple" solution.

Obviously the hidden field isn't rendered, but it is easily viewable from the source code.

Comment: I like your definition as "Client-side vulnerability", you're right it is not rendered but it is viewable from the source code thus revealing sensible information..the vulnerability relies here..thanks for answering